# Read a record via code behind for a sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

suppose i open a sqldatasource for binding on listview. 
I would like also to read a field on first record for print it. 
How can i access to my sqldatasource from code behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I where you I would use `(typeBeingBound)((ListViewDataItem)e.Item).DataItem` in the listView_ItemDataboundEvent.